# How to change the standard port for monero on linux and windows?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Where can I change the standard port for monero core wallet when installing on linux and windows?

Comment: The port the wallet used to connect to a demon, or the port the wallet RPC server listens to ?

Comment: I have a webserver and i want to install monero there and have my desktop connect to it, but I don't want to use a standard port.

Comment: So I assume this is the daemon port, and you'll be running the daemon on that server. I'll answer on that assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The monerod daemon listens to RPC commands on port 18081 by default (28081 for testnet). Wallets such as monero-wallet-cli will connect to this port by default to interact with the daemon. This default can be changed with the following monero-wallet-cli command line options:

--daemon-address a.b.c.d:N
 --daemon-port N

These will will use port N. For instance, if yo're running your webserver with a 1.2.3.4 external IP, and want to use port 8080, you'd use:

--daemon-address 1.2.3.4:8080

Note that if you allow your daemon RPC to be reachable from the Internet, you may want to set a user/password, using the --rpc-login username:password option to monerod (optional, since the daemon doesn't know your keys, only the wallet does), and use --restricted-rpc to avoid people doing things like mining on your daemon.